# Rancher Desktop - Windows - from container unable to connect to host machine of desired port

Tags: docker, docker-network, rancher-desktop

I'm trying to connect to Angular application running in port 3000 from Docker container ( Apache OIDC container ) using host.docker.internal. 
Log from Apache OIDC Container

```
 AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 172.28.32.1:3000 (host.docker.internal) failed"}
```

My IPConfig  
[image]

Angular Application in host machine is running 3000. 
**conclusion -**  
Able to hit the internet ( Google and some service ) 
Able to ping WSL VEthernet IP , still unable to hit my angular application running in port 3000 in my local machine.

 I have already tried firewall opening from rancher desktop FAQs

[image]

[image]